# Dimension in cube but not in the project SSAS

Tags: database, ssas, cube-dimension

I found out that my cube contains dimension, which i cannot find in the database project.
I cannot alter the dimension now.

How is this possible?

Comment: Is this cube in production? if so make sure you take a backup of the cube first. Then, create a new solution and choose "open analysis services project" as the project type. This allows you to import SSAS database model to visual studio, you can then edit the dimension you want and deploy.

Comment: This dimension is missing in the Visual studio project also